# HDFS datanode use all available space

Tags: hadoop

I have a 1TB (931GB usable) harddrive that I've dedicated to HDFS. I mount it at /hdfs. Here is my hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/hdfs</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/hdfs</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Usage:

```
% df -H  /dev/sdd1
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1       984G   78M  934G   1% /hdfs

 % hdfs dfs -df -h 
Filesystem          Size  Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://localhost  15.7 G   4 K     15.7 G    0%
```

Version:

```
% hadoop version
Hadoop 2.8.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 20fe5304904fc2f5a18053c389e43cd26f7a70fe
Compiled by vinodkv on 2017-06-02T06:14Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 60125541c2b3e266cbf3becc5bda666
This command was run using /opt/hadoop-2.8.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.1.jar
```

Why is HDFS using only a small fraction of the available space? How can I tell it to use all available space?

Answer (score 0):

The XML config was wrong:

`dfs.datanode.name.dir` → `dfs.datanode.data.dir`